# How can I update my function to show the clock that ticks every second

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setinterval

Please refer my code below

```
var DisplayTime = () => {
  return <h1 style={{ color: "white" }}> {new Date().toLocaleTimeString()}</h1>;
};

setInterval(DisplayTime,1000);

export default DisplayTime;
```

It shows the time when the function is called. I want it to update every second.

Comment: You have to use the `setInterval` where you import it, or you have to bake the `setInterval` inside the exported method

Comment: Sorry, i could not understand. Can you please elaborate a little ?

Comment: The current answer does what I mentioned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a state variable to store the `time` in, inside a `useEffect` you can create an `interval` to update the time every second. Don't forget to `clearInterval` inside the `useEffect cleanup`.

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [time, setTime] = useState(new Date().toLocaleTimeString());

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setTime(new Date().toLocaleTimeString());
    }, 1000);

    return () => {
      clearInterval(interval);
    };
  }, []);

  return <h1>{time}</h1>;
}
```

Try it out in [this Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-mountain-grcxv?file=/src/App.js).